# JUnit : is there a way for each test to show passed / failed in the logcat?

Tags: java, junit

JUnit : is there a way for each test to show passed / failed in the logcat ?

I am running so many tests so is there a way for each test to print passed / failed in the logcat. because at the moment I need to wait for the entire test to be run to see the final result.

Please suggest.

Comment: What is the purpose to show test results in logcat?

Comment: 1 - I will rather stop the test if there is any one failure. 2 - just for curiosity purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could define a [`TestWatcher`](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html#finished%28org.junit.runner.Description%29) for your test class. Override the `failed` and `succeeded` methods to add print statements accordingly.

You may wish to declare this in a parent class that all your tests sub-class, to avoid repetition.

Comment: @user2511126 Click the link. It has an example at the top.